# Confusing jQuery/ jsonp failure on Android emulator

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-emulator

I'm trying to call a service using jsonp on the andriod emulator:

```
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        $.ajaxSetup ({  
            cache: false  
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://10.0.2.2/uk-en/login/user",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(xml){
                $("#result").html('123');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                $("#result").html('XMLHttpRequest = ' + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest) + ", textStatus = " + textStatus + ', errorThrown = ' + JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            } 
        });
    }
```

I'm doing this on the HelloWorld app create following documentation on the phonegap site. My `index.html` is similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

This is the error I receive although this works from Firefox on my local machine:

```
XMLHttpRequest = {"READYSTATE":4,"STATUSTEXT":"SUCCESS"},TEXTSTATUS = PARSERERROR, ERRORTHROWN = {"MESSAGE":JQUERY1830456564654_32131 WAS NOT CALLED", "STACK":"ERROR:JQUERY1830456564654_32131 WAS NOT CALLED"\N AT FUNCTION.ERROR(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js:2:13215)
```

Anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

`JSONP` requires that the response be wrapped in some kind of **callback function**.

This is all assuming you're grabbing the content from another domain. If so, you're limited by the same [origin policy:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

So the server should respond with:

```
urFunction({....});
```

Comment: The response in firefox is wrapped. This is only occurring from within the Android emulator application.

Comment: I found the issue. My Android emulator can't see my local machine although I thought I had sorted this.